# Целочисленное округление на си

Tags: c++, c, микроконтроллеры

Как такой код

```
uint pt = 3240; // 3220..3260
uint w = 360; // 353..367

float pcf = round((float) pt/(float) w);
uint pc = pcf;

if (pc == 9) //....
```

сделать без float?  Чтоб отработало в прерывании в контроллере не особо занимая процессорное время.

Пробовал

```
pc = 102*pt/w/100;
```

но это не то что нужно. Ошибка будет расти на больших pt.

Comment: `(pt + w / 2) / w`. `(pt + w >> 1) / w` - у нас же микроконтроллер, а никто не поверит что компилятор такие вещи сам оптимизирует.

Comment: Списибо. Просто с флоат он тепленький, а с целыми числами холодный. Что там наоптимизирует компилятор я не могу знать)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2422712/6944845

Answer (score 3):

Округление - это когда от 0.5 вверх, меньше - вниз.

Посмотрим на дробь `p/q`. Пусть `p = kq + r`, тогда точный ответ

```
k + r/q
```

Нам надо, чтоб при `r/q` меньше 1/2 получался 0, при большем получалась 1. Сейчас все время 0. Но если мы прибавим к `r` половину `q`, то при `r/q` меньше 1/2, или `r < q/2` получится `r < q`, так что дробь все равно останется при целочисленном значении 0. Если же `r` больше или равна половине `q`, то получаем после прибавления ее значение от `q` до `q+q/2`, и `r/q` округлится до 1, что нам и надо.

Значит, для округления надо делить `(p+q/2)/q`.

Comment: *"поскольку могут быть неприятности при нечетном `q`"* — какие? (в `p = kq + к` опечатка)

Comment: При малом w погрешность будет.

Comment: @tocic Не делится нацело на 2.

Comment: Это сделает неверным результат `(p+q/2)/q`?

Comment: @tocic Мне казалось, что да, я даже на бумажке какой-то пример пробовал. Но может я и неправ.

Comment: @tocic Кажется, я был неправ. Убираю это замечание.

Answer (score 1):

Проверяй

```
uint pt = 3220; // 3220..3260
uint w = 360; // 353..367
//float pcf = round((float) pt/(float) w);
uint pc = (pt << 1) / w;
pc = (pc >> 1) + (pc & 1);
```